# Put suggested tags on the right hand side

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I'm looking at [a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/355246) right now and I see this:

[image]

[image]

Given that for the body of a question the suggested additions appear on the righthand side, I would argue that the same should be done for the tags. However, as illustrated above they now appear on the left.

For the sake of consistency I would request that these suggested tags are also displayed on the righthand side.

Comment: Oh, well then shouldn't they appear on the righthand side?

Comment: It's ambiguous enough to have confused me.

Comment: They should appear in the middle if it's a unified view that covers both versions.

Comment: @Bart Suggested feature, I guess; I've never been sure if UX bugs are bugs or feature requests.

Comment: @Bart *lol* Oh. "They currently appear on the left, but if they're intended to be a set of tags applicable to both versions, using colors to differentiate between added/removed/unchanged tags, perhaps they should appear in the middle. This makes it clearer the tags haven't been removed in the second post." Or just put before/after tags on both versions.